# Automatically activating GameBooster apps on my app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

My Samsung phone has a "GameBooster" application, it works automatically on games I download from Google Play, but I can't run it in my own game app. Also, other Android phones (eg Xioami) have a gamemode app, how can these phones know that my application is a game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I uploaded my game to Google play, it automatically worked and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:isGame="true"` on the application tag in your manifest file.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I think I need Play Games Services in my project